# how can i set time delay between two functions in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I build app which call to server.

it takes for 20 seconds - 30 seconds to get reply from server, because the system we use depending to outside service (connecting to our partners system).

before i can do the next, i must wait to get results.

is there any way to set the delay time for waiting reply???

thanks in advance

Comment: Show us how you are collecting the remote data.

Comment: i just send a Encrypted String and receive in boolean value: YES or NO

Comment: How do you send an encrypted string? `NSURLConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

### performSelector

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doNext) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0];
```

### NSTimer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(doNext) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

### dispatch

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 30.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self doNext];
});
```

Comment: is there any good other ways?????? 20s-30s is the max time to wait. i just want to wait until get values and doNext if not wait until 30s and return false.

Comment: You have not provided any other information. Paste an example of how you call and handle your data.

Comment: -(void)Loginwithusername: (NSString *)user andpass: (NSString *)pass andtoken:(NSString *)token
{
   
    requestLogin = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urllogin]];
 //[requestLogin setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
 [requestLogin setPostValue:pass forKey:@"password"];
    [requestLogin setPostValue:token forKey:@"device_token"];
 requestLogin.delegate = self;
 [requestLogin setTimeOutSeconds:90]; 
    [requestLogin setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];
 [requestLogin startSynchronous];

} i use like this my function login and get value true or false

Comment: Paste your code in your question. ASI should have a feature that does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use blocks in cases like these. That way you can send your request, and only proceed with code when you get a response back.